# fetching amount of views out of youtube api XSLT

Tags: xml, api, xslt, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to fetch the amount of views out of the youtube api, it worked well for the title, url and thumbnail, though it doesnt for the amount of views.

this is the XML code from which i'm trying to fetch (take a look at the last line):

```
<feed xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:app="http://purl.org/atom/app#" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/on_the_web</id>
<updated>2012-03-21T03:32:37.000-07:00</updated>
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"/>
<title type="text">On the Web</title>
<logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo>
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/on_the_web"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/on_the_web/batch"/>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/on_the_web?start-index=1&amp;max-results=25"/>
<link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/on_the_web?start-index=26&amp;max-results=25"/>
<author>
    <name>YouTube</name>
    <uri>http://www.youtube.com/</uri>
</author>
<generator version="2.1" uri="http://gdata.youtube.com">YouTube data API</generator>
<openSearch:totalResults>192</openSearch:totalResults>
<openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
<openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
<entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/LSNxrEa3Usw</id>
    <published>2012-03-07T01:09:29.000Z</published>
    <updated>2012-03-21T10:32:34.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"/>
    <category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat" term="Entertainment" label="Entertainment"/>
    <category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat" term="makena"/>
    <category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat" term="adele"/>
    <category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat" term="singing"/>
    <title type="text">2yr old Makena sings Adele...so cute</title>
    <content type="text">My 2yr old daughter loves Adele and sings along!</content>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSNxrEa3Usw&amp;feature=youtube_gdata"/>
    <link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/LSNxrEa3Usw/responses"/>
    <link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/LSNxrEa3Usw/related"/>
    <link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile" type="text/html" href="http://m.youtube.com/details?v=LSNxrEa3Usw"/>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/on_the_web/v/LSNxrEa3Usw"/>
    <author>
        <name>heatherfedorick</name>
        <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/heatherfedorick</uri>
    </author>
    <gd:comments>
        <gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/LSNxrEa3Usw/comments" countHint="2433"/>
    </gd:comments>
    <yt:hd/>
    <media:group>
        <media:category label="Entertainment" scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Entertainment</media:category>
        <media:content url="http://www.youtube.com/v/LSNxrEa3Usw?version=3&amp;f=standard&amp;app=youtube_gdata" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" medium="video" isDefault="true" expression="full" duration="105" yt:format="5"/>
        <media:content url="rtsp://v5.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnMUrdGrHEjLRMYDSANFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp" type="video/3gpp" medium="video" expression="full" duration="105" yt:format="1"/>
        <media:content url="rtsp://v5.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwnMUrdGrHEjLRMYESARFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp" type="video/3gpp" medium="video" expression="full" duration="105" yt:format="6"/>
        <media:description type="plain">My 2yr old daughter loves Adele and sings along!</media:description>
        <media:keywords>makena, adele, singing</media:keywords>
        <media:player url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSNxrEa3Usw&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player"/>
        <media:restriction type="country" relationship="deny">DE</media:restriction>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/LSNxrEa3Usw/0.jpg" height="360" width="480" time="00:00:52.500"/>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/LSNxrEa3Usw/1.jpg" height="90" width="120" time="00:00:26.250"/>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/LSNxrEa3Usw/2.jpg" height="90" width="120" time="00:00:52.500"/>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/LSNxrEa3Usw/3.jpg" height="90" width="120" time="00:01:18.750"/>
        <media:title type="plain">2yr old Makena sings Adele...so cute</media:title>
        <yt:duration seconds="105"/>
    </media:group>
    <gd:rating average="4.9061623" max="5" min="1" numRaters="18159" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"/>
    <yt:statistics favoriteCount="3144" viewCount="3134579"/>
</entry>
```

and this is the code for fetching the data and putting it in a own defined xml form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="/a:feed/a:entry">
<item>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">youtube</xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="a:title" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="author">
        <xsl:value-of select="a:author/a:name" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="url">
        <xsl:value-of select="a:link/@href" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="image">
        <xsl:value-of select="media:group/media:thumbnail[@width='120']/@url" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="score">
        <xsl:value-of select="yt:statistics/@viewCount" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</item>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

though the lines:

```
<xsl:attribute name="score">
    <xsl:value-of select="yt:statistics/@viewCount" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

simply won't return my score :(

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have posted as your stylesheet is not well-formed, in particular the namespace declaration with the prefix `yt` in

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'
```

is misplaced, it needs to be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
```

That is all that is wrong, as far as I can tell. I would however any XSLT processor expect to report that error so perhaps in your real code there are other or further problems. If you still have problems then post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem, including any error message you get and the name and version of your XSLT processor.

Comment: wow, that was just really stupid of me :P thanks! you have no idea how long I was looking for that :P